# ORA-00001 - But no name

Tags: oracle, constraint

We have a huge table with nested tables and such.  We are using Bulk Collect & FORALL to insert.

When loading data, I am getting this error:

ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated

There is no constraint name......so, how can I find out 1)  What or where is causing the error, and, 2) Which record it is?

I know you can keep exceptions with FORALL, but we are doing this in lots of 500, so it is hard to find out the actual record, and what constraint / nested table it is, etc.

I'm looking for any help anyone can give.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A possible bug for not displaying the constraint name with bulk DML and `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` clause:

[Bug 7210333 : CONSTRAINT NAME IN SQLERRM IS NOT OUTPUT WHEN SAVE EXCEPTIONS IS USED](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=bug&id=7210333)

To catch the records causing the error, you could use DML error logging as well:

```
create table t1(c1 number unique);

begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log('T1', 'T1_ERRORS');
end;
/
```

Insert data:

```
declare
  type t_varray is varray(4) of number;
  l_varray t_varray := t_varray(1, 2, 2, 3);
begin
  forall i in 1..l_varray.count
  insert into t1 values (l_varray(i)) 
    log errors into t1_errors
    reject limit unlimited;
end;
/
```

Actual data:

```
select * from t1;

        C1
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

Rows violating the constraint with row data and constraint name:

```
select * from t1_errors;

ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ ORA_ERR_MESG$                                                ORA_ERR_ROWID$       ORA_ERR_OPTYP$       ORA_ERR_TAG$         C1
--------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
              1 ORA-00001: unique constraint (BP.SYS_C0013693) violated                           I                                         2
```

Comment: That can be very useful......but does not work with nested tables. :( So, I'm not sure what to do.....